# Grails How to using GSP-Views and REST Webservice in the same Project

Tags: spring, security, rest, grails, view

I am very new in Groovy and Grails and need some help with my project.
I am using Grails 2.3.8 and the Spring Security Core plugin for Authorization. I created some domain-classes and generated all necessary files with "generate-all"-command. So I can edit my data with the normal gsp-views. This is working fine.
But now I have to extend this project with a REST Webservice (the views to edit data should stay). There are multiple way's to create Webservice I've seen, like Annotations with @Resource on the domain or an extendable RestfulController or I found plugins like Jaxrs.

Could anyone please help me to find out which is the best approach to add a REST Webservice on an existing project which should still work? Or does anyone has a example for something like this?

Thanks in advance,
sbr

EDIT: I'm doing it now with spring security core and acl plugin and the JAXRS plugin for REST api.
To secure the REST api I installed the spring security rest plugin. The authentification over rest api is working fine. BUT now I can't login on my UI Views which are secured by spring security core and acl. There is no error at login, but after click on login I'm never logged in. It is like nothing happens.
Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong or how I have to manage both authentifications?

Comment: I would recommend trying the Rest support provided by Grails

Comment: Could you explain me that a little more precisely please? Thanks.

Comment: The implementation choice depends a lot on why you are exposing resources in the first place.  Are you trying to provide progressive enhancement (providing a javascript SPA for some clients falling back to simple HTML for others), a public API for your application in addition to your request/response app, etc?

Comment: I simply like to have browser web application with CRUD-functionality for my data and I need a public API to access this data from smartphone app.
Please help.